# Win 7 crashes, PC reboots and says "Hard drive 0 not found" until I turn if off and on again

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, crash, reboot

I recently made the move from Windows XP to Windows 7. Since then, when my computer is on for a few hours it always ends up rebooting without warning. Then the BIOS won't recognize my hard drive (hard drive 0 not found).

If I turn off my computer and then on again, it boots normally.

Some details:

- Dell Dimension 9150
- Windows 7
- I updated the BIOS
- I updated all system drivers with the latest version from Dell (SATA, Chipset, etc.)
- Other drivers updated too (Graphic card, sound, etc.)

There is one thing that I tried after some Googling: I turned off the DMA access to the drives, but it's still rebooting after a few hours.

Any clue?

**UPDATE 2010/12/13**

Here are the events from the Event Log for today, from when I turned the computer on until it crashed:

19:17 - Error - ID 10016 - DistributedCom

20:06 - Error - ID 1008 - Customer Improvement Program (could not send data to Microsoft)

21:48 - Critical - ID 41 - Kernel-Power (System was restarted without proper shutdown)

21:48 - Error - ID 6008 - EventLog (Previous system down was not planned)

21:48 - Error - ID 1101 - EventLog (Audit Event ignored)

21:49 - Error - ID 10016 - DistributedCom

Both DistributedCom events have a description along these lines (translated from French):

The authorisation parameters specific to the application are not allowing Local Execeution for the COM server application with the CLSID 
{C97FCC79-E628-407D-AE68-A06AD6D8B4D1}
and the APPID 
{344ED43D-D086-4961-86A6-1106F4ACAD9B}
 to the SID AUTHORITY NT\User System (S-1-5-18) from the address LocalHost (LRPC usage). This security authorisation can be changed with the Component service administration tool.

**UPDATE 2010/12/31**

Here are the error messages I have on blue screens :
STOP C000007xA - Kernel_Data_Inpage_Error
"Unkown hard error"
C00000135 - Can't start because &hs is missing

Comment: Have you checked that the hard drive data and power cables are properly connected?

Comment: have you checked the Windows event log to see why it is rebooting?

Comment: I'd swap it out and see if the problem persists

Comment: I checked the data and power cables and they were connected properly. I swaped the data cables between my main and secondary drives to check if they are the cause of the problem.

Comment: My computer crashes with any power or data cable attached...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Kernel_Data_Inpage_Error

indicates an error reloading memory that was paged (swapped out) to disk. I'd run a check on the hard disk; it sounds like you might have something failing there.

Comment: You were right! Every diagnostic I ran said the drive was okay, but I had a feeling this was a hard drive problem. So I bit the bullet and bought a new drive, installed Windows and everything and voilà! System stable. Bonus check: Latter I plugged in my old drive to transfer files and my computer crashed just like it did, with paging errors in event viewer. Turns out this old drive is dying. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since that model is not officially supported by Dell for W7, it could be a bios bug that will never get fixed.

You could run hardware diagnostics on it, see if anything turns up.

[Click Me](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/format.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&deviceid=3841&libid=13&releaseid=R133063&vercnt=4&formatcnt=0&SystemID=XPS/DIMENSION%20400/9150&servicetag=&os=WLH&osl=en&catid=-1&dateid=-1&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&impid=-1&checkFormat=true)

Latest drivers from Intel, install in this order, reboot after each.

Chipset 32 and 64 bit
http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18494&ProdId=2115&lang=eng

Raid (IRST) 32 and 64 bit
http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=19607&ProdId=2115&lang=eng

Video 32bit
http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18223&ProdId=2115&lang=eng

Video 64bit
http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18228&ProdId=2115&lang=eng

.

Here is what Microsoft says about 7A errors

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559211(v=VS.85).aspx

.

Comment: Dell Diagnostics says everything is okay - thanks for the link.

Comment: Replace the cmos battery, then immediately enter the bios and load defaults and set the date and time.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't solve the problem

Comment: I did an edit to my answer to include the latest Drivers from Intel.

Comment: I installed the drivers and the situation is the same. I will get a new CMOS battery - I tried a reset and got a "low voltage" message at my first boot.

Comment: New battery installed: Computer still crashing. I updated my question with the different blue screen error messages I got.

Comment: Check my edit to my answer.